# How to read and XML file and convert the same to a CSV file using Azure function?, also the XML file name and the new CSV name should be parameterized

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-http-trigger

I want to convert an XML file to CSV which resides inside my Azure blob storage container using Azure function via Python code, but the problem is I need to pass the XML file name and the CSV file name inside the query parameter, while test/run. How can I do it?

I wrote a Python code but got a 500 error

```
from io import StringIO
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient 
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
import requests

constrin = "conn-str"

connection_string = constrin
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(r"func-data-01")
fileName = requests.params.get('fileName')
File_Name = container_client.get_blob_client(fileName)


blob = File_Name.download_blob().readall().decode("utf-8") #decode depends on the type of file. UTF is for CSV files.

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob)) #the file will be accessed and the data will be moved to dataframe and can be used further

print(f"file is found an the name is: {File_Name}")


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP-triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**Final-Output:**

[image]

**Query-param:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your requirement in my environment.

***I could read XML file which is available in Storage container and convert it to CSV file using Python Azure function.***

- Created a sample XML file and uploaded to Storage Container.

[image]

**My Python Azure function code:**

This function code downloads the **XML** file to local, converts to **CSV** and then upload it to ***Azure Storage Container***.

[image]

**init.py function**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import csv

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    connection_string = "<Storage_Connection_String>"
    container_name = 'test'


    # query parameters    
    xml_file_name = req.params.get('xml_file_name')
    csv_file_name = req.params.get('csv_file_name')


    # Create a BlobServiceClient object
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    # Get a BlobClient object for the XML file
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=xml_file_name)

    # Download the XML file to a local file
    with open("local_xml_file.xml", "wb") as my_blob:
        download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
        my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())

    # Parse the XML file and write the CSV file
    root = ET.parse("local_xml_file.xml").getroot()
    with open("local_csv_file.csv", "w", newline="") as my_csv:
        writer = csv.writer(my_csv)
        # Write the header row
        writer.writerow(["Title", "Author", "Genre", "Price", "PublishDate", "Description"])
        # Write the data rows
        for child in root:
            title = child.find("title")
            author = child.find("author")
            genre = child.find("genre")
            price = child.find("price")
            publish_date = child.find("publish_date")
            description = child.find("description")
            if title is not None and author is not None and genre is not None and price is not None and publish_date is not None and description is not None:
             writer.writerow([title.text, author.text, genre.text, price.text, publish_date.text, description.text])
        else:
            print("Error: Missing element in XML file")

    # Upload the CSV file to Azure Blob Storage
    with open("local_csv_file.csv", "rb") as my_csv:
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=csv_file_name)
        blob_client.upload_blob(my_csv)
    return func.HttpResponse(f"XML file converted to CSV file  successfully.")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]